# ¿ Como capturar click de boton html para llamar a un metodo en java android ?

Tags: java, android, html

Estimados gusto en saludarlos, estoy trabajando en Android Studio creando un entorno con WebView ,en este existe un botón que al presionarlo debe llamar a una función creada en java.¿ es posible abordar esta dinámica enlazando con  addJavascriptInterface()?. alguna orientación se los agradecería. Muchas gracias

Comment: Es posible realizar esto, pero buscas una opinión o tutorial?. Te sugiero agregar tu ejemplo. revisar [ask]

Answer (score 1):

primero necesitas crear una clase de interfaz

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Después agregar la interfaz al WebView con el siguiente código:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Y al final en tu codigo HTML hacer lo siguiente:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Puedes encontrar mas información en: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview